# Eslint dependency error, using refs in useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have written code which calculate amount of lines of typography in order for showing extra button or not, I go with refs and everything works as it should however I have eslint error

> ESLint: React Hook useMemo has unnecessary dependencies:
> 'boxRef.current' and 'typographyRef.current'. Either exclude them or
> remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'boxRef.current'
> aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the
> component.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

I don't want to disable this rule but I don't really have idea how to rewrite it to fix this warning. Does anyone has any suggestion?

my code:

```
 const boxRef = useRef(null);
  const typographyRef = useRef(null);

 const shouldExpand = useMemo(() => {
    if (!boxRef.current || !typographyRef.current) {
      return false;
    }

    const boxEl = boxRef.current as HTMLDivElement;
    const computedHeight = getComputedStyle(boxEl)
      .getPropertyValue('height');
    const height = Math.floor(
      Number(
        computedHeight.substring(0, computedHeight.length - 2), // to remove px
      ),
    );

    const typographyEl = typographyRef.current as HTMLParagraphElement;
    const computedLineHeight = getComputedStyle(typographyEl)
      .getPropertyValue('line-height');
    const lineHeight = Math.floor(
      Number(
        computedLineHeight.substring(0, computedLineHeight.length - 2), // to remove px
      ),
    );

    const computedPadding = getComputedStyle(typographyEl)
      .getPropertyValue('padding');
    const padding = Math.floor(
      Number(
        computedPadding.substring(0, computedPadding.length - 2), // to remove px
      ),
    );

    const output = Math.floor((height - padding) / lineHeight);
    return output > 7;
  }, [boxRef.current, typographyRef.current]);
```